# the preimage of a continuous function is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $f(x)=|x|$ in $R^d$, then can we show that for any measurable subset $E\subset R^1$, $f^{-1}(E)$ is measurable in $R^d$?

P.S. It should be noted that this is not true for general $f$ which is continuous (even monotonic), see Stein's book (In an exercises).

Comment: What can you say about $f^{-1}(E)$ where $E$ is open or closed (for a general continuous function)? How can we write *any* measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$ in terms of open and closed sets?

Answer (score 1):

The family of subsets
$$
\mathcal{C}:=\{E\subseteq\mathbb{R}\mid f^{-1}(E)\text{ is measurable in }\mathbb{R}^d\}
$$
is a sigma-algebra (check this) containing all sets of the form $(-\infty,a)$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ (why?) and hence
$$
\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})=\sigma(\{(-\infty,a)\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\})\subseteq\mathcal{C}.
$$